# How to add a Nix project as dependency in a Haskell Stack+Nix project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix

I'm trying to write a haskell project using *stack* + *nix*. My current *stack.yaml* and *shell.nix* are as follows:

```
resolver: lts-14.6
packages:
- .
nix:
  enable: true
  pure: true
  shell-file: shell.nix
```

```
{ghc}:
with (import <nixpkgs> {});

haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myproject";
  buildInputs = [ pkg-config libmysqlclient postgresql_10 pcre libsodium secp256k1 zlib ];
  PGPASSWORD = builtins.getEnv "PGPASSWORD";
}
```

Now, in my haskell project, I want to execute *tezos-client* and other tools provided by [tezos-baking-platform](https://gitlab.com/yunyan9chs/tezos-baking-platform/blob/9chs-tezos-only/). I can build it by running

> nix-build -A tezos.babylonnet.kit

The problem is, after building, I can find all the executable files in, for example, `/nix/store/bgqva3wgi3knivdk9pf7gdd0384hj2qf-tezos-0.0.0/bin/`. But they are not exposed to nix-env and I can't find any symlink for tezos in `~/.nix-profile/bin/`.

So, (1) how can I fix this? and (2) how can I set that *tezos-baking-platform* as a dependency of my haskell project? (i.e. through stack to ask nix for building tezos for me right before build my haskell project)

Comment: Nothing to your question, but wouldn't it be more comfortable to run `stack build`, `stack exec` inside of `nix-shell`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a working (but maybe not perfect) solution.

Because the *tezos-baking-platform* is not providing nix derivation, so the simplest way is to put the entire repository into the working repository and `import` its nix file. This will make `tezos.babylonnet.kit` available in nix so we can set it as a dependency directly.

```
{ghc}:
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
with import ./tezos-baking-platform/default.nix {};
haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "qq";
  buildInputs = [ tezos.babylonnet.kit ];
}
```

PS. Ideally, if the tezos-baking-platform provided a nix derivation, then we can do something like

```
{ghc}:
with (import <nixpkgs> {});

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "tezos-baking-platform";
  version = "0.0.0";
  src = fetchurl {
    url    = "https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-baking-platform/";
    rev    = "2f37c78a4b0ac26ee5e428711ab3c7ebeb9869fb";
    sha256 = "0h71ivsva7hfqy0zy1pbx68a4i8lbqln3k9zkw0j2rgain39844r";
  };
}

haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myproject";
  buildInputs = [ tezos-baking-platform ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enter a shell with the executables in the PATH: `nix shell` (by default it references `shell.nix`).

To add `tezos-baking-platform` as a dependency I think you just add it in `buildInputs`. If this is from a `channel` named `tezos` you will have to import this:

```
tezos = import <tezos> {};

...

tezos.tezos-baking-platform
```